# Installing a WatchKit App via simctl

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator, watchkit

I created a basic hello world WatchKit app, and it runs fine on the simulator via XCode 6.3 Beta. However, when I try to deploy the app to the simulator via simctl, results aren't as pleasant. Here's what I tried:

**boot&launch sim**

```
xcrun instruments -w "iPhone 6 (8.3 Simulator)"
```

**install app**

```
xcrun simctl install "iPhone 6" com.test.foo.app
xcrun simctl install "iPhone 6" com.test.foo\ WatchKit\ Extension.appex/
xcrun simctl install "iPhone 6" com.test.foo\ WatchKit\ App.app/
```

When I try to run any of the apps, either from the simulator or by using simctl launch, the main app just crashes.

**launch app via simctl**

```
xcrun simctl launch "iPhone 6" com.test.foo
xcrun simctl launch "iPhone 6" com.test.foo\ WatchKit\ App
```

I'm assuming I shouldn't use `simctl install` for the WatchKit pieces, as separate app icons are created unlike when running from XCode. Digging into the simulator's system logs, it appears that when I run from XCode the main app is installed first, and the WatchKit pieces are installed as plugins vs separate apps. Not sure how to achieve this from command line, but there must be a way. Nothing documented that I can find, so maybe someone on the inside can help?

Answer (score 1):

OK, got this worked out.

**Deploying and Launching WatchKit apps via command line**

So, all of the needed WatchKit resources are contained within the main app's bundle. Only need one install command, and then one launch command to launch the WatchKit app. The big gotcha was that app identifiers on the device are not the same as the generic bundle identifier.

**boot&launch sim**

```
xcrun instruments -w "iPhone 6 (8.3 Simulator)"
```

**install app (after you build it)**

```
xcrun simctl install "iPhone 6" com.test.foo.app
```

**launch watchkit app (notice the identifier!)**

```
xcrun simctl launch "iPhone 6" com.test.com-test-foo.watchkitapp
```